# Show that $Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}$ and $\tilde{Z}$ are independent.

Tags: normal-distribution

> > Let $Z\sim N(a\iota_{\nu},I_{\nu}), a\in\mathbb{R}$ whereat
> >     $$
> > \iota_{\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{pmatrix},~~~I_{\nu}=\text{diag}(1,\ldots,1).
> > $$
> >     Show that $Z^TZ=(Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}})^T(Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}})+\nu\tilde{Z}^2, \tilde{Z}:=\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Z_i/\nu$. Furthermore, show that $Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}$ and $\tilde{Z}$ are stochastically independent and determine the distributions of $Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}$ and $\tilde{Z}$.

Hi, I think the first and the last task are not that difficult:

It is $Z^TZ=\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Z_i^2$ and
$$
(Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}})^T (Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}})=\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}(Z_i-\tilde{Z})^2=\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Z_i^2-2\tilde{Z}\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Z_i+\nu\tilde{Z}^2\\=\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Z_i^2-2\nu\tilde{Z}^2+\nu\tilde{Z}^2=\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Z_i^2-\nu\tilde{Z}^2,
$$
so 
$$
(Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}})^T (Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}})+\nu\tilde{Z}^2=\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Z_i^2=Z^TZ.
$$

Moreover, the $Z_i, i=1,\ldots,\nu$ are independent (because the covariance matrix is diagonal), so it follows that 
$$
\tilde{Z}\sim N(a,1/\nu).
$$
Write $Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}=c+I_{\nu}Z, c:=-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}$, then it follows that
$$
Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}\sim N(a\iota_{\nu}-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}, I_{\nu}).
$$

This should be ok. But how can I show that $Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}$ and $\tilde{Z}$ are independent?

Comment: Are $\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}$ and $\tilde{Z}$ the same thing? If they are, you can't have $Z-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}\sim N(a\iota_{\nu}-\tilde{Z}_{\iota_{\nu}}, I_{\nu})$, because $\tilde{Z}$ is random.

Comment: It is $\tilde{Z}=\frac{1}{\nu}\sum_{i=1}^{\nu}Z_i$ and $\tilde{Z}\iota_{\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}\tilde{Z}\\\vdots\\\tilde{Z}\end{pmatrix}$. So its not the same. Nevertheless you are right...

Comment: How can I then determine the distribution of $Z-\tilde{Z}\iota_{\nu}$?

Answer (score 0):

Well the mean of 
$Z-\tilde{Z} {\iota_{\nu}}$ is 0, so the value of $a$ might as well be 0.

You can show independence of $Z-\tilde{Z} {\iota_{\nu}}$ and $\tilde{Z}$ by looking at their covariances, and using the property of Multivariate Normal (uncorrelated $\Rightarrow$ independent).

You can also find the covariance matrix of $Z-\tilde{Z} {\iota_{\nu}}$. I wouldn't call the resulting distribution Multivariate Normal though, because the resulting matrix will not be full rank. Try the 2-dimensional case to see more clearly what's going on.

Comment: Whats the covariance of $Z-\tilde{Z}\iota_{\nu}$? Do not know how to calculate that? Isnt it $E((Z-\tilde{Z}\iota_{\nu})(Z-\tilde{Z}\iota_{\nu})^T)$?

Comment: Just look at each pair of components separately. Start with 2-dim case if you're stuck.

Comment: I am confused now... on the diagonals it is $Var(Z_i-\tilde{Z})=E((Z_i-\tilde{Z})^2)$. Otherwise it is $E((Z_i-\tilde{Z})(Z_j-\tilde{Z}))-E((Z_i-\tilde{Z})E(Z_j-\tilde{Z})$

Comment: You would rather use the identity $Cov(X+Y, W) = Cov(X,W) + Cov(Y,W)$

Comment: Sorry do not understand what you mean. Do not know this identity.

Comment: Can you pls give me more help? :-)